# How do I trigger function inside ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-init

Im trying to count an array length from a second query inside a ng-repeat.

This is my html:

```
<tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="j in jobpositions | filter:searchString | orderBy:'startdate'">
        <td ng-init="applications(j.id)">{{jobapplicationsperjob.length}}</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Here is the function:

```
$scope.applications = function(jid){
    var JobapplicationsPerJob = $resource('/ats/services/jobapplicationsperjob/:jid');
        $scope.jobapplicationsperjob = JobapplicationsPerJob.query({jid:jid});
        console.log($scope.jobapplicationsperjob);
    }
```

This is the console.log:

```
[$promise: Object, $resolved: false]
    0: f
    $promise: Object
    $resolved: true
    length: 1
    __proto__: Array[0]
[$promise: Object, $resolved: false]
    $promise: Object
    $resolved: true
    length: 0
    __proto__: Array[0]
[$promise: Object, $resolved: false]
    $promise: Object
    $resolved: true
    length: 0
    __proto__: Array[0]
```

As you can see, it twice returns a value of 1 but in the HTML it's always 0.

Comment: Okey I found out that he will display the last array length value in each field. Then the question is how do you post the value of the init function?

Comment: What do you mean by _post the value of init_?

Comment: In the TD element im triggering the ng-init. the function inside gives me back an array. I want to place the length value of that array.

Comment: I know this isn't an answer to your problem .... but your plan is to make an AJAX request for each item in ng-repeat ?